# bluestacks stuck on loading channels

Tags: android, android-emulator, bluestacks

Bluestacks stuck up on loading channel with a circle in the middle...

so far I had uninstalled and re-installed bluestacks several times but ended with the same issue.

[image]

I am using fastest internet connection in my pc using LAN / Wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i  found the solution , it seems that blue stacks trying to connect to some kind of store and he couldn't, i fix it up by running an app called psiphone 3 , its a free vpn app , after u run it u will notice that nothing change and the loading page still appear just wait for 5 minutes and the store list will appear after this try to download any launcher u want , and then ur problem will be solved 
sorry bad english.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue and it looked like that the application 'com.bluestacks.gamepophome' is missing or corrupt. You can check the log file 'C:\ProgramData\Bluestacks\GameManager.log'.
The solution I applied is to use a different Launcher. I used [ADW Launcher](http://www.freewarelovers.com/android/apps/adw.launcher) as an replacement. The benefit is that I can use more of the default Android apps as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing constant issues while running Bluestacks i.e Bluestacks Loading Screen problem then there's no need to worry anymore you can easily fix the issue by trying the following steps :

1 - Install Latest Bluestacks App player and install all additional software's required by bluestacks for proper operation

2 - Give Users Account Full Control Access

For more details and step by step guide visit here :

http://www.rushinformation.com/bluestacks-loading-problem-screen-fix/

Answer (score 0):

It was stuck and blinking for me. I resolved it by:

1. Go to Settings > Apps > All Apps
2. Select GamePopMain
3. Force Stop and Clear Data

And voila - it started working again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and what I figured is the GamePopMain is a launcher for BlueStacks.  It has some issue in the Mac version for sure and on windows may have them as well.  Install any other launcher and you will stop getting crashes and will be able to use it with out problems.